# set border for grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to set border for my UITableView. I dont want any seperators to be highlighted. If I set a clear clor for seperator, the border for table is also set to clear color. I Just want the black colored border for the table. How to do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code.

Also import QuartzCore framework

```
tableview.layer.borderWidth=4.0;
```

tableview.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];